# Tic Tac Toe stopping and not sure why. Very new to Python and have not looked at any code examples for Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, random, tic-tac-toe

This is a very early project in my Python career. Only watched a few tutorials and then jumped in so ELI5 please.

It runs a couple of turns but then it just freezes and im not sure why. It takes turns and then says when there is a winner. There is a bot with real bot logic.

The game starts by defining a spots array which is what the users see. There is 10 spots so it was easier for me to use the array spots 1 for the 1st spot (bad use of arrays, i know). There is a similar thing with spotBooleans which is used for checking whether a spot is taken. The numbers in the 90's are defaults. When a player places a spot, it turns that into an int 1, and enemy will be an int 2.

Most of the action is at the bottom with the while playing loop where it prints most of the data and asks you where to go. Then it checks for winners after you go, and goes to trigger the bot which uses basic algorithms and logic to try to win like a human would. Currently has nothing for stopping human moves. Then it checks if the bot is the winner.

Somewhere here it just stops in its tracks and I can not find why.

Again, I know this is poor code. I know some Java but I am not good at Python so far. Just trying to get the logic right and then the clean code will come up next along with simplifying things.

```
import random
import time

spots = ["", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]
spotBooleans = [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]

start = False

whosturn = 1

while True:
    spots = ["", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]
    spotBooleans = [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
    start = False
    whosturn = 1

    while start == False:
        playerchoice = input("Would you like to be 'x' or 'o'")

        x = False
        o = False

        if playerchoice == "x" or playerchoice == "X":
            x = True
            print("Player is X")
            start = True
        elif playerchoice == "o" or playerchoice == "O" or playerchoice == "0":
            o = True
            print("Player is O")
            start = True
        else:
            print("Try again.\n\n")
            start = False

    print("Starting: ")
    playing = True


    def gorobot(whosturn):
        global x
        global spots
        global spotBooleans
        global playing
        global start

        if x:
            robotsymbol = "o"
        else:
            robotsymbol = "x"

        while whosturn == 2:
            if spotBooleans[1] == spotBooleans[2] == 2:
                if spots[3] == "-":
                    spots[3] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[3] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[3] == spotBooleans[2] == 2:
                if spots[1] == "-":
                    spots[1] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[1] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[1] == spotBooleans[3] == 2:
                if spots[2] == "-":
                    spots[2] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[2] = 2
                    whosturn = 1

            elif spotBooleans[4] == spotBooleans[5] == 2:
                if spots[6] == "-":
                    spots[6] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[6] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[4] == spotBooleans[6] == 2:
                if spots[5] == "-":
                    spots[5] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[5] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[5] == spotBooleans[6] == 2:
                if spots[4] == "-":
                    spots[4] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[4] = 2
                    whosturn = 1

            elif spotBooleans[7] == spotBooleans[8] == 2:
                if spots[9] == "-":
                    spots[9] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[9] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[7] == spotBooleans[9] == 2:
                if spots[8] == "-":
                    spots[8] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[8] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[8] == spotBooleans[9] == 2:
                if spots[7] == "-":
                    spots[7] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[7] = 2
                    whosturn = 1

            elif spotBooleans[1] == spotBooleans[5] == 2:
                if spots[9] == "-":
                    spots[9] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[9] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[9] == spotBooleans[5] == 2:
                if spots[1] == "-":
                    spots[1] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[1] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[9] == spotBooleans[1] == 2:
                if spots[5] == "-":
                    spots[5] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[5] = 2
                    whosturn = 1

            elif spotBooleans[3] == spotBooleans[5] == 2:
                if spots[7] == "-":
                    spots[7] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[7] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[7] == spotBooleans[5] == 2:
                if spots[3] == "-":
                    spots[3] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[3] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[7] == spotBooleans[3] == 2:
                if spots[5] == "-":
                    spots[5] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[5] = 2
                    whosturn = 1

            elif spotBooleans[3] == spotBooleans[6] == 2:
                if spots[9] == "-":
                    spots[9] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[9] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[3] == spotBooleans[9] == 2:
                if spots[6] == "-":
                    spots[6] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[6] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[6] == spotBooleans[9] == 2:
                if spots[3] == "-":
                    spots[3] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[3] = 2
                    whosturn = 1

            elif spotBooleans[1] == spotBooleans[4] == 2:
                if spots[7] == "-":
                    spots[7] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[7] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[1] == spotBooleans[7] == 2:
                if spots[4] == "-":
                    spots[4] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[4] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[4] == spotBooleans[7] == 2:
                if spots[1] == "-":
                    spots[1] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[1] = 2
                    whosturn = 1

            elif spotBooleans[2] == spotBooleans[5] == 2:
                if spots[8] == "-":
                    spots[8] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[8] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[2] == spotBooleans[8] == 2:
                if spots[5] == "-":
                    spots[5] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[5] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
            elif spotBooleans[5] == spotBooleans[8] == 2:
                if spots[2] == "-":
                    spots[2] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[2] = 2
                    whosturn = 1

            else:
                botMove = random.randint(0, 9)
                if spots[botMove] == "-":
                    spots[botMove] = robotsymbol
                    spotBooleans[botMove] = 2
                    whosturn = 1
                else:
                    print("The Bot is a moron! " + str(botMove))


    def checkforwinners():
        if spotBooleans[1] == spotBooleans[2] == spotBooleans[3]:
            print("Winner!")
            return True
        elif spotBooleans[4] == spotBooleans[5] == spotBooleans[6]:
            print("Winner!")
            return True
        elif spotBooleans[7] == spotBooleans[8] == spotBooleans[9]:
            print("Winner!")
            return True
        elif spotBooleans[1] == spotBooleans[4] == spotBooleans[7]:
            print("Winner!")
            return True
        elif spotBooleans[2] == spotBooleans[5] == spotBooleans[8]:
            print("Winner!")
            return True
        elif spotBooleans[3] == spotBooleans[6] == spotBooleans[9]:
            print("Winner!")
            return True
        elif spotBooleans[1] == spotBooleans[5] == spotBooleans[9]:
            print("Winner!")
            return True
        elif spotBooleans[3] == spotBooleans[5] == spotBooleans[7]:
            print("Winner!")
            return True
        else:
            print("No Winners!")
            print(spots)
            print(spotBooleans)
            return False


    while playing:
        print(str(spots[1]) + " " + str(spots[2]) + " " + str(spots[3]))
        print(str(spots[4]) + " " + str(spots[5]) + " " + str(spots[6]))
        print(str(spots[7]) + " " + str(spots[8]) + " " + str(spots[9]))
        print("\n")

        spotChoice = input("Where would you like to place your " + playerchoice + "?")
        spot = int(spotChoice)

        if spots[spot] == "-":
            if x:
                spots[spot] = "x"
                spotBooleans[spot] = 1
                if checkforwinners():
                    playing = False
                    start = False
                    break
                whosturn = 2
                gorobot(2)
            else:
                spots[spot] = "o"
                spotBooleans[spot] = 1
                if checkforwinners():
                    playing = False
                    start = False
                    break
                whosturn = 2
                gorobot(2)
                if checkforwinners():
                    playing = False
                    start = False
```

Comment: Im not gonna read all of that ... but i would hazard a guess your robot is in an infinite loop and cannot select a spot with the given logic

Comment: You say you haven't looked at any code examples for tic tac toe -- I'd suggest doing exactly that!  You're spending a lot of time reinforcing bad habits with your current approach (use of globals, lots of copied and pasted code, etc); reading some good code examples will help steer you in a better direction by showing you simpler ways to accomplish the same goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under certain conditions, your code causes an infinite loop inside the `gorobot` function.

For example, after a few tries, I got a `spotBooleans` list that looks like this:

```
[90, 1, 1, 93, 2, 1, 2, 97, 98, 99]
```

And a `spots` list that looks like this:

```
['', 'x', 'x', '-', 'o', 'x', 'o', '-', '-', '-']
```

In that state, when the code enters the while loop inside `gorobot`, it goes through this code path.

```
elif spotBooleans[4] == spotBooleans[6] == 2:
    if spots[5] == "-":
        spots[5] = robotsymbol
        spotBooleans[5] = 2
        whosturn = 1
```

`spotBooleans[4]` and `spotBooleans[6]` are both 2, so it enters the `elif` block, but `spots[5]` is "x", so it doesn't enter the inner `if` block. This means the `whosturn` variable is not updated, so the code doesn't exit the `while whosturn == 2:` loop. And the `spotBooleans` and `spots` lists are not updated, so on the next loop round the program follows the exact same code path.